# My 'Select List' is incorrect with the current Group By clause. How do I fix this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    artist.firstname
    ,artist.lastname
    ,AvgRating = AVG(painting.rating) OVER ( PARTITION BY painting.artistid )
    ,MaxRating = MAX(painting.rating) OVER ( PARTITION BY painting.artistid )
    ,MinRating = MIN(painting.rating) OVER ( PARTITION BY painting.artistid )
FROM 
    painting
JOIN 
    artist ON painting.artistid = artist.id
GROUP BY
    artist.firstname
    ,artist.lastname
HAVING COUNT(painting.title) > 2
```

But I get this error:

> Column 'painting.ArtistId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Line: 1

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected result

Comment: This is the question prompt: Show each artist's first and last name, their average rating (as AvgRating), and their lowest and highest ratings (as MinRating and MaxRating). Only include those artists who have more than two paintings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help

```
SELECT
     artist.firstname
    ,artist.lastname
    ,AvgRating = AVG(painting.rating)
    ,MaxRating = MAX(painting.rating)
    ,MinRating = MIN(painting.rating)
FROM painting
JOIN artist ON painting.artistid = artist.id
GROUP BY
     artist.firstname
    ,artist.lastname
HAVING COUNT(painting.artistid) > 2
```

Comment: If first name and last are not unique then artist.id can be added to both select & group by.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add ArtistId to the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
    artist.firstname
    ,artist.lastname
    ,AvgRating = AVG(painting.rating) OVER ( PARTITION BY painting.artistid )
    ,MaxRating = MAX(painting.rating) OVER ( PARTITION BY painting.artistid )
    ,MinRating = MIN(painting.rating) OVER ( PARTITION BY painting.artistid )
FROM painting
JOIN artist ON painting.artistid = artist.id
GROUP BY
    artist.firstname
    ,artist.lastname
    ,painting.artistid
HAVING COUNT(painting.title) > 2
```

Comment: I did this and added painting.rating too.  It won't return any rows.